Questions about the Pohozaev identity for toda system.
Consider the following Toda system:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-\Delta u_1=2 e^{u_1}-e^{u_2} \\
-\Delta u_2=-e^{u_1}+2 e^{u_2}
\end{array}\right.
$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
I'm reading Analytic aspects of the Toda system: I. A Moser-Trudinger inequality, in which a step of Pohozaev identity is applied.
They have the Pohozaev identities as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}\label{1}
& -R \int_{\partial B_R}\left(\left|\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}\right|^2-\frac{1}{2}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2\right)=2 \int_{\partial B_R} R e^{u_1}-4 \int_{B_R} e^{u_1}-\int_{B_R} e^{u_2} x \nabla u_1, \\
& -R \int_{\partial B_R}\left(\left|\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial r}\right|^2-\frac{1}{2}\left|\nabla u_2\right|^2\right)=2 \int_{\partial B_R} R e^{u_2}-4 \int_{B_R} e^{u_2}-\int_{B_R} e^{u_1} x \nabla u_2,
\end{aligned}
$$
in arbitrary $B_R$ without boundary condition.
Multiply $x \cdot \nabla u_1$ on both side of
$$\tag{1}
-\Delta u_1=2 e^{u_1}-e^{u_2}.
$$
For $\int_{B_R} x \cdot \nabla u_1 e^{u_1}$, I compute as follows:
$$
\nabla \cdot (xe^{u_1})=（\nabla \cdot x） e^{u_1}+x \cdot \nabla(e^{u_1})=2e^{u_1}+e^{u_1}x \cdot \nabla u_1.
$$
So $$
\int_{B_R} x \cdot \nabla u_1 e^{u_1}=\int_{B_R}\nabla \cdot\left(x e^{u_1}\right)-2 e^{u_1}=R\int_{\partial B_R}e^{u_1}-2\int_{B_R} e^{u_1}.
$$
So the RHS of (1) is
$$
2R \int_{\partial B_R} e^{u_1}-4 \int_{B_R} e^{u_1}-\int_{B_R} e^{u_2} x \nabla u_1,
$$
which is the RHS of the result
$$\tag{2}
-R \int_{\partial B_R}\left(\left|\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}\right|^2-\frac{1}{2}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2\right)=2 \int_{\partial B_R} R e^{u_1}-4 \int_{B_R} e^{u_1}-\int_{B_R} e^{u_2} x \nabla u_1,
$$
we want.
So the only thing left is to calculate$$\int_{B_R} x \cdot \nabla u_1\Delta u_1  ,$$
which is
$$\tag{3}
\int_{\partial B_R}(x \cdot \nabla u_1)( \nabla u_1 \cdot \mathbf{n})-\int_{B_R}\nabla u_1 \cdot \nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)=R \int_{\partial B_R}|\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}|^2-\int_{B_R} \nabla u_1 \cdot \nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)
$$
I have no clue about the rest term, where the $\frac{R}{2} \int_{\partial B_R}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2$ in (2) comes from?
Or can we transform the term $\int_{B_R} \nabla u_1 \cdot \nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)$ in (3) to $\frac{R}{2} \int_{\partial B_R}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2$?

I did some calculation and think this may works.
We can expand $\nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)$ :
$$
\nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)=I \cdot \nabla u_1+ \nabla\left(\nabla u_1\right)  \cdot x
$$
which is $$
\nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right)=\nabla u_1+\nabla^2 u_1  \cdot x  .
$$
Now let's deal with
$$
\int_{B_R}\left(\nabla u_1 \cdot \nabla u_1+\nabla u_1 \cdot\left(\nabla^2 u_1 \cdot x\right)\right)  .
$$
Note that $$
\nabla u_1 \cdot\left(\nabla^2 u_1 \cdot x\right)=\frac{1}{2} x \cdot \nabla\left(\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2\right) \text {. }
$$
Using the divergence theorem:
$$
\int_{B_R} x \cdot \nabla\left(\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2\right) =\int_{\partial B_R} R\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2 -2 \int_{B_R}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2 .
$$
Thus finally we have
$$
\int_{B_R} \nabla u_1 \cdot \nabla\left(x \cdot \nabla u_1\right) =\frac{R}{2} \int_{\partial B_R}\left|\nabla u_1\right|^2
$$
